# Why would the C standard (whatever is the latest) forbid this program due to strict aliasing?

Tags: c, strict-aliasing

It is clear to me that the C standard forbids (does not define the behavior of) this program, but it is not clear why it has to be this way. Why are the aliasing rules such that one cannot write this program?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<stdalign.h>

#define SIZE 512

unsigned char buffer[SIZE];
size_t free_slot = 0;

void* alloc(const size_t bytes, const size_t alignment)
{
   
     const uintptr_t start = (uintptr_t)(buffer+free_slot);
     const size_t adjust = (size_t)(start % alignment);
     const size_t placement = free_slot + adjust;
     const size_t next_free_slot = placement + bytes;

     printf("start=%ld\n",start);
     printf("adjust=%ld\n",adjust);
     printf("placement=%ld\n",placement);
     printf("next_free_slot=%ld\n",next_free_slot);
   

   if(SIZE < next_free_slot) return NULL;
   
   free_slot = next_free_slot;

   return buffer+placement;
   

}

struct thing {
  uint64_t x;
  uint64_t y;
};


int main()
{
  int* p1 = alloc(sizeof(int),alignof(int));
  printf("--------------\n");
  printf("alignof(struct thing)=%ld\n",alignof(struct thing));
  printf("--------------\n");
  struct thing* p2 = alloc(sizeof(struct thing),alignof(struct thing));

  *p1 = 143;
  memcpy(p2,&(struct thing){1,2},sizeof(struct thing));

  printf("%d\n",*p1);
  printf("%ld\n",p2->x);

  return 0;

}
```

Would it be possible to amend the standard to permit such a program or is this a hopeless endeavor?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241154/discussion-on-question-by-anonymouscoward-why-would-the-c-standard-whatever-is).

Answer (score 8):

> It is clear to me that the C standard forbids this program

Not really, it doesn't cover what will happen if you type pun from a character array into a struct - it is undefined behavior, since it violates a "shall" in C17 6.5/7, but not a constraint.

Regarding all the "strict aliasing sucks am I right?" rants... yes and no. The original purpose of these rules was to disallow wild and crazy conversions. The C99 rationale 5.10 chapter 6.5/35 shows this example:

> ```
> int a;
> void f(int * b)
> {
>   a = 1;
>   *b = 2;
>   g(a);
> }
> ```
>
> It is tempting to generate the call to g as if the source expression were `g(1)`, but `b` might point to `a`, so this optimization is not safe. On the other hand, consider
>
> ```
> int a;
> void f( double * b )
> {
>   a = 1;
>   *b = 2.0;
>   g(a);
> }
> ```
>
> Again the optimization is incorrect only if `b` points to `a`. However, this would only have come about if the address of a were somewhere cast to `double*`. The C89 Committee has decided that such dubious possibilities need not be allowed for.

This is the original rationale and C99 extended the unclear rules of C89 a bit with the introduction of *effective type*, for better and worse. The rules are still very much unclear, but the original intention is to allow compilers to not having to make weird assumptions as the above. So far it is a perfectly sensible assumption that compilers should be allowed to make.

Unfortunately somewhere in the early 2000s, some compilers most notably gcc decided to abuse this in order to perform optimizations. Suddenly you couldn't do things like `uint8_t arr[2]; ... *(uint16_t*)arr` because that's strictly speaking a strict aliasing violation. Until C99 compilers had generated sensible code without such optimizations, but past C99 some chose to go haywire. The situation has improved somewhat over the years but we can still not rely on compilers to generate "the expected" code in my little `uint16_t*` conversion above.

The number of exceptions to the strict aliasing rules in C17 6.5/7 leaves a lot to be desired. For example it is perfectly sensible to type pun between various unsigned integer types - anyone who's done hardware-related programming understands this. But this isn't allowed.

And as another example there's no mentioning what will happen with type qualifiers - nobody in the whole world seems to be able to answer this: [What rules are there for qualifiers of effective type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65356861/what-rules-are-there-for-qualifiers-of-effective-type) - I have no idea of what rules there are myself.

It's unclear how to use arrays in relation to effective type... the list goes on. There's numerous Defect Reports about various details of these rules but they haven't been improved.

---

As for if your program contains any strict aliasing violations and how to fix it:

- `unsigned char buffer[SIZE];` has the effective type (array of) `unsigned char`.
- `const uintptr_t start = (uintptr_t)(buffer+free_slot);` is fine assuming that you don't end up with misalignment, but that's a separate issue.
- When you de-reference the pointer from the caller side and make a lvalue access as `int` or a struct type etc, there is a strict aliasing violation, since this is not one of the allowed exceptions in the list 6.5/7. The other way around - going from a larger type and accessing byte by byte with character type pointers would be fine.

So to fix it you have to make something like this, for the `int` example:

```
typedef union
{
  int i;
  unsigned char bytes[sizeof(int)];
} intalias_t;
```

Now you can do:

```
intalias_t* p1 = alloc(sizeof(int),alignof(int));
(*p1).i = 143; // well-defined
```

Because `(*p1).i` is "an lvalue expression that" is "an aggregate or union type that includes" "a type compatible with the effective type of the object". That is, the union contains a character type array which is (supposedly) compatible with the effective type which is also a character type. "Supposedly" since the rules are muddy when it comes to array access. And if your original array or the one in the union contained a type qualifier, nobody knows(?) what will happen.

When in doubt/as a rule of thumb, use `-fno-strict-aliasing`.

Comment: *some compilers most notably gcc decided to abuse this in order to perform optimizations*  I think "abuse" is probably too harsh a term here.  The strict aliasing rule as written for C99 allowed an entire family of significant performance optimizations to be done.  It's more of an unintended consequence.  No one predicted the impact of, "Hey, this opens up a whole new field of optimizations for C code."

Comment: @AndrewHenle: The term "abuse" is entirely appropriate here.  The intention of the Standard is to allow compilers to perform optimizations in situations that would not adversely affect their customers, and the authors recognized that people wanting to sell compilers would be able to judge their customers' needs better than the Committee ever could.  Programs that rely upon implementations behaving "in a documented fashion characteristic of the environment" may be non-portable but correct, and the authors of the Standard expressly said that they did not wish to demean non-portable programs.

Comment: @Lundin, it is not reasonable to conclude from the fact that nobody did answer your question about qualifiers in effective types that nobody in the whole world is *able* to answer it.  [Counterexample provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70744898/2402272).

Comment: @JohnBollinger Well I've sent several experts to view that question but none could answer. I'm not entirely sure it can be answered either, but I'll check out your reply.

Answer (score 5):

> Why is the aliasing rules such that one cannot write this program?

The strict-aliasing rule, which has been in every version of ISO C published to date, does not say that you cannot write the program, or even that a C implementation cannot accept it and execute it with the effect you seem to want.  Rather, this is one of the comparatively many places where the specification holds that the program, though syntactically correct and satisfying (I think) all language constraints, has *undefined behavior*.

There are various reasons for the spec to leave program behavior undefined under some circumstances, or, as in this case, to explicitly specify that it is undefined.  In the case of the strict aliasing rule, [the rationale document for C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) (there is no such document for more recent versions of the specification) speaks to this decision:

> The types of lvalues that may be used to access an object have been restricted so that an
> optimizer is not required to make worst-case aliasing assumptions

(p. 59)

That full discussion is too much to quote here (it's a bit more than a full page of the document), but you may find it of interest.

> Would it be possible to amend the standard to permit such a program or is this a hopeless endeavor?

The ISO has a working group devoted to maintaining the language specification, and it releases revisions from time to time.  In principle, then, it is possible that such a change could be made.  In practice, it is doubtful that this particular change would be accepted because it would have wide-ranging impact for comparatively small gain.

Comment: So the only way to make my program have defined behavior(while conforming to the standard) is to declare the buffer as something like `extern void* buffer;` and set it up in a linker script, so as to eliminate any declared type.

Comment: @anonymouscoward, that, or some analogous mechanism for associating memory with `buffer` externally to the C language.

Comment: @anonymouscoward: Either use a compiler that doesn't support strict aliasing (Microsoft's, Apple's), or disable strict aliasing in the compiler (e.g. `-f-no-strict-aliasing` in GCC). The performance benefits (< 10%) isn't worth the extremely high risk of unintended consequences (even if you can find a programmer that tolerates strict aliasing you can guarantee they will get it wrong eventually as there's too many other things programmers need to worry about).

Comment: @Brendan *The performance benefits (< 10%) isn't worth the extremely high risk of unintended consequences*  What "risk"?  Just don't write code that invokes UB - it's not hard to know what type of variable you're working with. If you can't keep track of your variable types, you're in WAAAY over your head in C code to begin with and `-fno-strict-aliasing` isn't going to come close to saving you from disaster.  It's a champagne cork for a Titanic passenger.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Is it possible to update that link to the rationale document from a secure site that doesn't set off browser alerts? It's almost baffling that open-std.org doesn't offer https connections.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: The Standard expressly provides that allocated storage which is used to hold an object of one type may later be rewritten as some other type and then read using the latter type, but clang and gcc do not reliably support this except when using `-fno-strict-aliasing` or compiler-specific directives.  Since using clang/gcc optimizations without `-fno-strict-aliasing` risks unintended consequences even when processing 100% portable programs, why not avoid such risk and simply use an option that will make even clang and gcc generate correct code.

Comment: Sorry, @sj95126, I have no such URL.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Sorry - meant "you cast your pointer to `uint16_t *`". Ran out of space and didn't realize until 5 minute edit timer expired.

Comment: @supercat *The Standard expressly provides that allocated storage which is used to hold an object of one type may later be rewritten as some other type and then read using the latter type*  Where? And with *risks unintended consequences even when processing 100% portable programs*, are you referring to this: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14319

Comment: @AndrewHenle: The Standard states that the act of writing storage only sets the Effective Type of that storage until the next time it is modified.  It doesn't expressly say what happens to the Effective Type the next time the storage is modified, but the only sensible implication of saying the Effective Type is only set until the storage is modified would be that the next modification will behave as though the object had no Effective Type, thus setting the Effective Type anew. Both clang and gcc are prone to treat a sequence of operations that will leave storage holding the same bit pattern...

Comment: ...as it started with as though it never modified the storage, even if the bit pattern would change during the sequence of operations, and the operations use a type other than the Effective Type it started with.  Effectively, any operation which uses one type to write a bit pattern that storage previously held using some other type may occasionally behave as though it resets the Effective Type of the storage to the earlier type.

Comment: @supercat *Both clang and gcc are prone to treat a sequence of operations that will leave storage holding the same bit pattern...*  AFAIK that only happens under the conditions of the bug report I posted above: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14319 Frankly, I can't say I disagree much with the GCC maintainer's response:  when you do `yp->y = 1`; and then ***read*** from `xp->x`, that ***read*** violates strict aliasing and UB is invoked, invalidating any result. I understand arguments otherwise, but if that's the only case that happens it's a bit disingenuous to generalize it.

Comment: See https://godbolt.org/z/Gd6K65YPs for an example of the "optimization" I'm talking about.  If `i`, `j`, and `k` are all zero, storing 123 to `p2[j]` should set the effective type of `*p` to `longish`, after which the code will read the storage as type `longish`, and write 888 to it as type `long`, which should definitely modify it.  Writing `temp` to the storage should leave the type as `long`, which should be the correct type to read it in the last statement, but gcc collapses out the writes using p4 and p5.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: What fraction of non-trivial programs for freestanding implementations do not contain constructs which the Standard characterizes as UB?  Note that the term "UB" identifies constructs which are *non-portable or erroneous*, which includes constructs which are *non-portable but correct*.  Support for non-portable constructs is a Quality of Implementation issue outside the Standard's jurisdiction, but quality general-purpose implementations will seek to support such constructs when they are useful regardless of whether the Standard requires that they do so.

Comment: @supercat *What fraction of non-trivial programs for freestanding implementations do not contain constructs which the Standard characterizes as UB?* So?  That's hardly an excuse for deliberately writing code that invokes UB. Re "See godbolt.org/z/Gd6K65YPs for an example of the "optimization" I'm talking about. ...", I'm still trying to figure that one out - with a lot of things still to do around the home before going back to work tomorrow.

Comment: @AndrewHenle For why it's so hard (for me and the majority of the most skilled/experienced developers on the planet) think of it like juggling cats. With only one cat (strict aliasing alone) it's trivial. With 2 cats (strict aliasing and integer overflow) it's reasonable. Most people are juggling 20+ cats (the software's purpose, multiple threads, SIMD, spectre mitigations, multiple languages, revision control, ...) - one less cat to juggle makes a huge difference.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: So far as I can tell, the fraction of non-trivial programs for freestanding implementations that are free of what the Standard calls "Undefined Behavior" is zero.  When the Standard says that implementations may process such actions "in a documented manner characteristic of the environment", that wasn't just a vague thing that might happen.  That's how implementations intended to be suitable for low-level programming worked before the Standard was written, how they were expected to keep working, and it's the concept that made C useful for low-level programming in the first place.

Comment: @Brendan: A dialect of C which is designed to allow compilers to be mathematically proven correct, called CompCert C defines the behavior of many constructs the C Standard calls UB, but refrains from defining one concept the C Standard does define: there is no general permission to manipulate the bits of pointer objects using character types.  The notion that unrestricted UB is good for optimization only holds in those rare usage scenarios where, for every input where behavior isn't rigidly defined, all possible actions would be considered equally acceptable.  The notion is...

Comment: ...counter-productive and dangerous when applied in any other situation.  Further, a substantial fraction of the optimizations in C that would be safe 99% of the time cannot be proven sound because they're not.  The reason clang and gcc seem impressive is that their design philosophy is to make any "optimizations" that they can't 100% prove to be unsound, as opposed to limiting themselves to optimizations that can be guaranteed correct.

Answer (score 5):

As others have mentioned, strict aliasing allows for certain optimization to be made.  And given that these optimizations are useful, the standard committee is unlikely to remove it.

That being said, particular implementations do have methods of getting around this.  In particular, gcc has the `malloc` attribute.  From the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes):

> ```
> malloc
> malloc (deallocator)
> malloc (deallocator, ptr-index)
> ```
>
> Attribute malloc indicates that a function is malloc-like, i.e., that
> the pointer P returned by the function cannot alias any other pointer
> valid when the function returns, and moreover no pointers to valid
> objects occur in any storage addressed by P. In addition, the GCC
> predicts that a function with the attribute returns non-null in most
> cases.
>
> Independently, the form of the attribute with one or two arguments
> associates deallocator as a suitable deallocation function for
> pointers returned from the malloc-like function. ptr-index denotes the
> positional argument to which when the pointer is passed in calls to
> deallocator has the effect of deallocating it.

So if you compile with gcc and declare your function like this:

```
void* alloc(const size_t bytes, const size_t alignment) __attribute__((malloc))
```

Then you can safely use the returned memory as though it was returned by `malloc`, and strict aliasing can still be used elsewhere in the program.

---

Upon further reflection, given that several compilers support attributes of some type, it would make sense to standardize many of these to give application developers more control in how code can be compiled.  Given that C has been historically viewed as a "portable assembler" but standards have caused a divergence from that, putting support for such low-level behavior in the standard would probably be well-received.

Answer (score 3):

> Would it be possible to amend the standard to permit such a program or
> is this a hopeless endeavor?

The C Standard (ISO/IEC 9899) is maintained by ISO/IEC JTC1/SC22/WG14 - participation of which is open to anyone; nominations are made via your appropriate National Body (eg BSI in the UK)

Once a participant in the Working Group, you are free to submit proposals to change the Standard... if you can gain enough support within the WG, it is included in the next draft.

But any such proposal would need to address all the consequences, side-effects or any unwanted outcomes - and remember that WG14 has a Prime Directive of "Do not break existing code" (no matter how already broken that code may be).

The draft then goes through the formal approvals process - formal votes at Committee Draft, then Draft International Standard and finally Final Draft International Standard.

So, if you have a good solid argument for change, it is possible to change the standard; however, I wouldn't hold out much hope in changing this!

*Disclaimer: I am a UK delegate to WG14 (as well as the MISRA liaison)*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241155/discussion-on-answer-by-andrew-why-would-the-c-standard-whatever-is-the-latest).

Answer (score 1):

The C Standard does not "forbid" such constructs in Conforming C Programs that make no claim of being Strictly Conforming C Programs.  It allows implementations to process code in ways that would render such programs meaningless in cases where doing so would benefit their users (e.g. by allowing useful optimizations), and makes no effort to forbid implementations from doing so in cases where that would be detrimental to their users, because they never imagined that compiler writers would process programs in gratuitously meaningless fashion and use the fact that the Standard allows them to do so as an excuse to claim that the programs were "broken".

The C Standard explicitly acknowledges that implementations may offer stronger memory semantics than mandated by the Standard (N1570 5.1.2.3p9: "EXAMPLE 1 An implementation might define a one-to-one correspondence between abstract and actual semantics: at every sequence point, the values of the actual objects would agree with those specified by the abstract semantics. The keyword volatile would then be redundant.")  Since the defined behaviors of such an implementation would be indistinguishable from one that didn't define such a correspondence, such a specification would be meaningless if it didn't serve to define behavior in situations that would *otherwise* invoke Undefined Behavior.

Further, an important thing to note about the Standard is that a failure to define the behavior of a construct does not imply a consensus agreement that no compilers should be expected to process it meaningfully, but merely that there wasn't a consensus agreement to require that all compilers process the construct meaningfully *even on platforms where the cost of offering any behavioral guarantee consistent with sequential program execution would exceed any benefit such a guarantee might offer to a programmer*.

The notion that UB was intended to require programmers to jump through hoops to avoid various situations at all costs, even on platforms that could cheaply offer useful behavioral guarantees, is a modern notion which directly contradicts the intentions of the Standard's authors as documented in the published Rationale document (search C99 Rationale).